# "Cannot resolve symbol" when using ES6 `import` syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm, commonjs

[Here](http://www.qimingweng.com/react-modal-dialog/) an example is given how to import certain classes from a module:

```
import {ModalContainer, ModalDialog} from 'react-modal-dialog';
```

However, PhpStorm (latest EAP) gives me an error:

[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'ModalDialog']

I installed the package with `npm install react-modal-dialog` and it is present in `node_modules`.

The equivalent `var {ModalContainer, ModalDialog} = require('react-modal-dialog');` works fine.

Comment: Have you set the js language version to ECMA script harmony?

Comment: Are you transpiling the code before executing it?

Comment: @winhowes Yes, happens in both "ECMAScript 6" and "JSX Harmony" mode.

Comment: I think destructuring doesn't work with import.  I have to do import React from 'react-native'; and then var { Text, View } = React to workaround the warning.

Comment: It's [not destructuring](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19086#comment=27-1213285) (at least it's not meant to be), it's the [import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import): "Import multiple members of a module. This inserts both foo and bar into the current scope."

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this when setting up a React project and all i did was **download the import's typescript definition**, in my case just searched for `react`.

[image]

Instructions for adding libraries to your project can be found on [webstorm's help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#d36066e272).

Comment: Which library is `react-DefinitelyTyped`? I installed the libraries `react-router` and `react-router-dom` and that resolved the missing import for `Route`, but my `Switch` imports are still not being recognized.

Answer (score 6):

I think it caused by PHPStorm. The IDE can't *understand* the `import` syntax when import a CommonJS module.

I got this warning when using WebStorm 2016.1.2, too.

**Taking `react` and `react-router` as example:**

- `react` is a CommonJS module, developed with ES5 syntax;
- `react-router` is developed with ES2015 syntax, and compiled by Babel.

WebStorm 2016.1.2 can resolve `Link` exported by `react-router` module, but can't resolve `createClass` exported by `react` module.

**Update**:

`browser-sync` is a CommonJS module developed with ES5, too. But it works well on WebStorm, WebStorm can resolve all API exported by `browser-sync`.

It baffled me that WebStorm can't resolve `react` exported API.

Comment: There are plenty of sources on the internet saying PhpStorm understands ES6, your answer claims it doesn't. Please add details/references.

Comment: @AndreKR You can compare `react` with  and `react-router`, the IDE can resolve the API exported by `react-router`, but not `react`.

Comment: This is the legitimate explanation. Sadly, 4 months later I still can't find a workaround.

Comment: Is there any library download that resolves `Switch` imports?