# React Code-Splitting: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I'm trying to introduce code-splitting to my project, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. The error I get is:

[image]

I have a monorepo setup with a `lib/` workspace that contains the entire react library I'm creating, and a `demo/` workspace that just imports that react module and displays it, for testing purposes.

I think the issue is how these two interact and where the chunks are output or something, but can't figure it out.

My files are like this:

### lib/webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    maps: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'Map',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[s]?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: {
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                }
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ],
        include: /\.module\.[s]?css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.[s]?css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /\.module\.[s]?css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            rootMode: 'upward'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  externals: {
    // Use external version of React
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  },
  // NOTE: @claus added options to fix files not being watched
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
  }
}
```

### Folder structure

```
lib/ // In this project we try to use code splitting using React.Lazy()
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
demo/ // Includes the lib module for testing purposes
  package.json
babel.config.js
package.json
```

### demo/package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "maps": "link:../map/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I got this right, you are using `React.Lazy` in `lib`?

`demo` probably has it's own webpack config. Can you also share that?

Comment: @bamse `demo/` is just configured as a simple `react-scripts` app, without any custom Webpack config. I updated my answer to include the `demo/package.json`.

Comment: The error is thrown when trying to load a bundle chunk that isn't available. I think your `demo` app should (and does) the code splitting. I don't see how you could split in chunks a library. You use `React.Lazy` in `lib`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown when trying to load a bundle chunk that isn't available.

It is my understanding that code splitting is used for applications, not libraries.

Using code splitting for a library would mean that you would have to deliver multiple chunks as `dist` - not a single file like your settings

```
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index.js',
```

I'm not sure code splitting works for libraries - or what would be the benefit of it.

Using code splitting **in `demo`** means that needed pieces from `lib` will be bundled in demo's chunks. 
You would have to use `React.lazy` in `demo`, not in `lib`, and when building `demo`, each `React.lazy` will generate a new bundle. 
`demo` has access to all the `lib` source files (or single file dist) and only what is needed will end up in the built app.

I would guess you used `React.lazy` in `lib` and this mixes things up.

I hope this helps!

---

Extra questions/info:

1. why do you need code-splitting? is your `demo` app bundle getting too big?
2. Take a look at webpack's [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and make sure your `lib` is *tree-shakable* :) This way you can use code splitting in `demo` and not worry about it in `lib`

Comment: 1. It's not that the `demo` app is getting to big, is that the `lib` in itself is getting to big. When I build the lib for production distribution, I get the following warning: `WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance. index.js (1.73 MiB)`. So I wan't to improve performance as much as I can, that's why I wan't to do some code splitting.
2. I'll take a look at tree-shaking as well, but don't think that will improve things that much.

Comment: You are on the right path! The warning is thrown by the `demo` build. Using `Reacl.lazy` in `demo` will split the 1.73MiB bundle into multiple smaller bundles. I just wanted to point out that this is something you control in `demo`.

Comment: Tree-shaking is something webpack does in order to bundle only the needed code in the production bundle. This means that it will only pick what is needed from `lib`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You can ignore tree-shaking for starters. I thought it makes sense to know about it in the context but it might also complicate things. To fix your error: make sure you use `React.lazy` in `demo` and not in `lib`

Comment: Ok, thank you! Will do some more testing then. But the demo app is just a super tiny app that just imports the `lib/` and directly displays that. Can this still be optimized? My thought was that when the library is built into a 1.7mb single `.js` file, there is nothing `demo` then can do to reduce that import.

Comment: Just so you know, `demo` is not used for production, so `yarn build` only builds `lib`. Demo is just to test the library when developing. So if the optimization happens in demo, then I have to tell all the consumers of the library to use React.lazy. :/

Comment: My 2 cents: Since `demo` is just a demo app you can ignore the warning. If your finished product is just the `lib` you should make sure tree-shaking works on it - ex: make sure that when using the lib (`import { Foo } from 'my-lib';`) in an app bundled with tree-shaking, only `Foo` related code ends up in the app bundle.

Comment: You could use webpack-bundle-analyzer to see what gets bundled in the `demo` bundle and how much of that is `lib` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: Ok, thank you. The `lib` just exports one single Map component, so don't think tree shaking will do much. Most of the size is related to mapbox gl, but there is some content in the map that would be nice to lazy load, do reduce the initial load size of the Map component. But everything needs to be imported when the library is consumed.

Comment: Looks like this issue describes what I'm searching for, and it looks like it's not possible. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6818

Comment: Yeap! Considering your `lib` will be used in built apps you should explore other library targets so the apps using it can only take what they use. It might not be possible considering your scenario - sometimes _that's just the bundle size_ :)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue and my solution was the following changes in this file

```
.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js
```

Change from:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'renderer.prod.js',
  },
```

Change to:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../src/dist'),
    publicPath: '../dist/',
    filename: 'renderer.prod.js',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days looking for a solution
And I still don't understand why it works when using libraries with react-script
But as soon as I create a library on a clean webpack, I get an error
When using react-script, I can export components with lazy, but in webpack - I get an error
In addition, the export from the library is underlined (as described in this topic: [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741847/cannot-resolve-symbol-when-using-es6-import-syntax))

I tried to figure out the build and checked the configurations of babel, webpack and ts
I will attach my configurations, maybe it will be informative for someone

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'library', 'index.ts'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|woff|woff2)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    preferAbsolute: true,
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    mainFiles: ['index'],
    alias: {},
  },
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'TestPackage',
      type: 'umd',
    },
    filename: 'index.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  }
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "loose": true,
        "modules": "umd"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
    }
  },
}
```

The application importing the library is a regular react-script without any settings (and I don't think it should be important, the library is built as UMD

Is there any explanation why this might not work on webpack, but works on react-script?